# MS Dynamics CRM - database GUIDs

Tags: guid, dynamics-crm

I was using the SDK for CRM, and printed out the PK on a bunch of instances of one of our entities. I repeated it with the database's filtered views, and got the same answer:

```
    1a6c691d-391a-de11-8b0e-0050568407cb
    bd7b0ff0-391a-de11-8b0e-0050568407cb
    ed272bfe-391a-de11-8b0e-0050568407cb
    ... and so on ...
```

These don't appear to be valid GUIDs. For one, they LOOK wrong - they're nearly identical, a property that GUIDs haven't had since the old version 1 & 2 GUIDs that were based on MAC addresses and clock time. Moreover, however, is the fact that a certain nibble in a GUID indicates the GUID's version - that nibble is incorrect here. (First nibble of the third section, ie: 1a6c691d-391a-***d***e11-8b0e-0050568407cb) - valid values are 1-5) (Generate a GUID using MS's GUID Generator - that slot will always be 4. (At least for the version I have.))

Are these GUIDs, or just IDs, and how do I know?

Comment: I've noticed this as well.  They refer to their ids as guids everywhere I can see but there's no clear indication.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right that they are GUIDs and that they are sequential.  These keys are not generated by CRM.  They are generated by SQL Server.

SQL Server has a GUID type called uniqueidentifier.  It can be configured as either NEWID() or NEWSEQUENTIALID().  NEWID() will generate a new GUID every time.  NEWSEQUENTIALID() generates a GUID the first time and then sequentially increments it on subsequent database inserts.

So you have discovered that Dynamics CRM is configured for NEWSEQUENTIALID().

More info about this is here:  http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1600

Comment: Wow, thanks. I wasn't sure I was ever going to get a straight answer to that one. Did some more research and found this: http://www.fotia.co.uk/fotia/DY.19.NewSequentialId.aspx - seems that they can be called GUIDs since they have your MAC in them.

Comment: Interesting article, thanks for posting it.  It explains why CRM uses the NEWSEQUENTIALID() - because of the db perf benefits.

Comment: I'm wondering @DavidMcDonald if you have a reference source to cite.  I am clearly seeing sequential values on inserted entity records but I have no idea how CRM is generating these... there is no default constraint defined and no identity setting...

Comment: Related question: Does anyone know if the same GUID can be used as the PK for records of different entity types or does a PK GUID need to be unique across all entity types?